# JavaScript: Comparing two objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to compare two objects to make a new object.

```
original = [
            {id: "A1", name: "Nick", age: 20, country: 'JP', code: 'PHP'}
           ]

edited = [
          {name: "Mike", age: 30, country: 'US'},
          {id: "A1", name: "Nick", age: 25, country: 'US', code: 'PHP'}
         ]
```

1. Compare two objects ('original' and 'edited')
2. If 'id' is set, compare the same ids' data, and take the data from 'edited', and get ONLY the 'id' and the data that is edited.
3. If 'id' is not set keep the whole data

The final object I want is like below;

```
final = [
         {name: "Mike", age: 30, country: 'US'},
         {id: "A1", age: 25, country: 'US'}
        ]
```

I've been trying this using filter, but I can't get desired result...

Comment: Please add the code you tried using filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) .

**Updated** with all key pair match

- Validate the edited array id value is available in original array using `Array#map` and `indexOf` function
- If not push entire object to new array
- First recreate the original array to object format like `{key:[value]}`
- Then match each key value pair match or not with forEach inside the reduce function

```js
var original = [{id: "A1", name: "Nick", age: 20, country: 'JP'}];
var edited = [{name: "Mike", age: 30, country: 'US'},{id: "A1", name: "Nick", age: 25, country: 'US'}];

var ids_org = Object.keys(original[0]).reduce((a,b,c)=> (a[b]=original.map(a=> a[b]),a),{});

var res = edited.reduce((a, b) => {
  if (b.id) {
      Object.keys(b).forEach(i=>{
      if(ids_org[i].indexOf(b[i]) > -1 && i != 'id')
         delete b[i];
      })
     a.push(b);
  } else {
    a.push(b);
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(res)
```

Comment: I didn't think about using `reduce`...!! but I want to compare two objects and extract all the difference.
For example, if the 'county' was also the same in 'original' and 'edited', I need to delete that as well, not only 'name'...

Comment: `The final object I want is like below;` is not like that .Could you change array as you expect.Your requirement not same with your expect result

Comment: I edited 'orginal' and 'edited'  objects, please take a look

Comment: you need to delete same value of key value pair.But expect id right?

Answer (score -1):

use de structuring to extract out id from the object.
use lodash isEqual method to compare and later add back the id to the object.